# Unable to start Spring boot Application from Eclipse luna using tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot REST application. The application can be deployed as war file directly in tomcat. It works as expected.
But when i try to start the tomcat from eclipse (like run on server ), it does not start the server.

I am using sprint boot latest version, with tomcat 7.
    Any pointers or suggestions to try out is also appreciated.Please let me know, if any configuration needs to be changed in eclipse or tomcat.

**Adding complete log as requested :-**

```
16:04:28.198 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjtools-1.8.2.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-nodep-3.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/databaseabcMmodule-1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/guava-15.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/abcMmodule-1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/trailmanagement-1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.0.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.0.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.1.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/json4s-ext_2.10-3.2.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/json4s-native_2.10-3.2.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.10.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/smkimodule-1.0.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-annotations-1.3.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-core_2.10-1.3.5.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-models-0.8.8.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-spring-mvc-ui-0.2.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-springmvc-0.8.8.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.12.jar, file:/D:/workspacetrail/workspace/Sep12/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Appname/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar]
16:04:28.204 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageFilter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void uk.co.workspacetrail.config.WebConfig.setSpringSwaggerConfig(com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig.handlerMappings; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/workspacetrail/exception/AppnameApplicationException2
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
```

Comment: Show full log in place of "Could not autowire method.................................."

Comment: Thanks injecto...I have added.it was a big line that's why edited the same.

Comment: Using Eclipse Luna and tomcat 7.Any suggestions

Comment: according to log `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/workspacetrail/exception/AppnameApplicationException2` jvm can't find `AppnameApplicationException2` class. If it exists, try manually add it to classpath.

Comment: The application works fine, while deploying the war file manually on tomcat.I mean by copying the war file to tomcat webapps and starting the tomcat.